# Using modulo in a hash function to propery insert into a table

Tags: c, hash, modulo

I have a hash table set up and I want to implement my insert function to properly insert key value pairs into the proper locations. Here is the code for the the setup of the table and its functions...

```
//Hash table entry structure
typedef struct entry_s {
    int key;
    int value;
    struct entry *next;
}entry_t;

//Hash table structure
typedef struct hash_table_s
{
    entry_t **entries;
    int size;
    int locks;
}hash_table_t;

//Hash function
int hash(int i, int n){
    return i % n;
}

//New table entry
entry_t *new_entry(int key, int value){
    entry_t *entry = (entry_t *) malloc(sizeof(entry_t));
    entry->key = key;
    entry->value = value;
    entry->next = NULL;
    return entry;
}

//Create new hash table
hash_table_t *new_table(int n, int k){
    hash_table_t *table = (hash_table_t *) malloc(sizeof(hash_table_t));
    table->entries = (entry_t **) calloc(n, sizeof(entry_t *));
    table->size = n;
    table->locks = k;
    return table;
}

//Insert key value pair into hash table
void insert(hash_table_t *table, int key, int value){
    printf("table size %d\n", table->size);
    printf("key %d\n", key);
    int index = hash(key, table->size);
    printf("hash %d\n", index);
    entry_t *entry = table->entries[index];
    if (entry == NULL)
    {
        table->entries[index] = new_entry(key, value);
        table->size++;
        printf("null table\n");
    }
    else {
        while (1){
            //Update value for multiples
            if (entry->value == value){
                entry->key += key;
                printf("1\n");
                break;
            }
            //End of chain, add new entry
            else if (entry->next == NULL){
                //entry->next = (new_entry(key, value))->next;
                table->entries[index] = new_entry(key, value);
                printf("2\n");
                break;
            }
            //traverse the chain
            else{
                printf("3\n");
                //entry = entry->next;
            }
        }
    }
    //unlock???
}
```

The hash function is required to be i % n where n is the number of entries and is also provided in the command line when executing the program. i is supposed to be the key in a key value pair. The issue I am running into I believe is what hash I am saving the key value pair to. When ever I try to save multiple pairs to the table they keep writing over the last pair and I only have one thing saved to the table. Here is the main function that calls everything, as well as the command line to execute.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("\n");

    int n = atoi(argv[1]);
    int k = atoi(argv[2]);

    hash_table_t *pt = new_table(n,k);

    insert(pt, 1, 111);
    insert(pt, 1, 111);
    insert(pt, 1, 222);
    insert(pt, 1, 333);

    print_table(pt);

    free_memory(pt);

    return 0;
}
```

```
dpb@ThinkPad:~/Documents/CSE_420/P3$ ./par_hash_table 10 2
```

The print function and free_memory function were left out to save room and reduce confusion but all they do is print the table and free malloc. Here is the output from executing...

```
table size 10
key 1
hash 1
null table
table size 11
key 1
hash 1
1
table size 11
key 1
hash 1
2
table size 11
key 1
hash 1
2

Hash Table
-------------------
Index:1, Key:1, Value:333
-------------------
```

The output in theroy should print 3 indexes with the 3 different key value pairs.

I am not sure if I am understanding exactly how hash functions work, if someone could let me know if I need to finish implementing a linked list to handle collisions if that is the issue. I really just don't know what to ask or where to start with this issue.

Comment: Your requirement is weird. We commonly have 2 kinds of mapping: simple mappings where a key can only have one value (the latter replacing the former) and multiple mappings where a key can have as many values as it was given *whether the values are equal or not*. But in all cases a key should NEVER change. You should give the precise specifications of your *table*.

Answer (score 1):

```
        if (entry->value == value)
            entry->key += key;
            printf("1\n");
            break;
        
   
        else if (entry->next == NULL){
            //entry->next = (new_entry(key, value))->next;
            table->entries[index] = new_entry(key, value);
            printf("2\n");
            break;
        }
```

you're printing the '1' first if on the loop (if (entry->value == value) ) when table is not empty but then
entry->key += key happens, so next times will be:  else if (entry->next == NULL) (note that '3' is never printed due to the 'break;' previous on 1st and 2nd if).